# How to fix "SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file"?

Tags: php, database, sqlite

I'm making a telegram bot that uses the pokemon api, but when I try to store the players informations into the database the PDO sqlite error shows up: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file in file.example

```
     * DataBase connection
     *
     * @return $pdo 
     */
    public function connect()
    {
        $pdo = new PDO('sqlite:database/tabela.db');

        return $pdo;
    }

 /**
     * Add the player informations into the database
     *
     * @param  integer $id
     * @param  string  $name
     * @param  string  $pokemon
     * @param  string  $type
     * @return void
     */
    public function addPokemon(int $id, string $name, string $pokemon, string $type)
    {
        $db = new DataBase();
        $db = $db->connect();
        
        $statament = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO `pokedex` (`id`, `nome`, `pokemon`, `type`) VALUES (:id, :nome, :pokemon, :type)");


        $statament->bindValue(":id", $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $statament->bindValue(":nome", $name,   PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statament->bindValue(":pokemon", $pokemon, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $statament->bindValue(":type", $type, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $result = $statament->execute();

    }
```

Comment: Does it have the correct permissions?

Comment: I think it has, i used this same code to my study crud and this error hasn't shown up